# Node JS : send asynchronously produced data

Tags: node.js

I am Creating WebSite Crawling App, which will take site url and then starts crawling entire site asynchronously.

Now here i will send response of given url with its status code as in 200, 404 etc.

But then all the other url on that particular page will be going through the same process but as response is already sent so how the other urls response code will be sent.

please suggest how to send updated value in response again after sending it once ?

Comment: Elaborate a bit.  Your question isn't very clear at all.

Comment: It still isn't clear.  Great, you have a crawler but what are you sending responses to?  Why are you using HTTP?

Comment: Hello Brad, Once i got site url i will send response in node js to result page with status of that particular page. and now in background all links on that will be processed for status and as it proceeds all updates should be send to result page. But As in node once response is send we can not send other response so how will send latest responses ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a page that receives updates without reloading the page.  For that, use AJAX and/or Web Sockets.  Take a look at Socket.IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much can't modify a response after its sent. I think there are exceptions to this, but you probably don't want to use them. I think you have a couple of options

- Catch all your callbacks and send one response
- Open up some kind of tcp connection (socket.io?) and stream the data.

Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Thanks Brad and Zeke, i am using socket.io to implement this problem.